# WordPress htaccess RewriteRule with Multiple Variables

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress site in development. "Pretty URL" structured permalinks are enabled currently, works fine. I have various RewriteRules in my .htaccess file (they are listed before and **not** mingling with the WordPress rules in the same file) that work fine. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) /www.domain.com/riacms/wp-content/themes/wptheme/images/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*) /www.domain.com/riacms/wp-content/themes/wptheme/fonts/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([0-9]+)/ /www.domain.com/catalog/?aid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What I am trying to get working is

```
RewriteRule ^details/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) /www.domain.com/details/?aid=$1&lot=$2 [QSA,L]
```

If I simply change `[QSA,L]` to `[QSA,L,R=301]` this works perfect... but that is not the intended outcome.

I have enabled mod_rewrite.c logging on the Apache 2.4 server and it returns the following (edited out the timestamps and useless info):

```
- rewrite 'details/66/35' -> '/www.domain.com/details/?aid=66&lot=35'
- trying to replace prefix /var/www/html/www.domain.com/ with /www.domain.com/
- internal redirect with /www.domain.com/details/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
- rewrite 'details/' -> '/www.domain.com/index.php'
- trying to replace prefix /var/www/html/www.domain.com/ with /www.domain.com/
- internal redirect with /www.domain.com/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
- pass through /var/www/html/www.domain.com/index.php
```

All I get is a 404 Error. Every. Single. Time.

I've confirmed, in various ways, that the regex I am using will indeed work fine. In fact, I have even used this EXACT line without WordPress and the rule works perfect. The issue here is something with WordPress but I can't place my finger on it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: check if your `details` page exist in pages or post. It seems htaccess rules are working fine but it is wordpress who is not able to find `details` page.

Comment: Thank you Furqan Aziz. The details page indeed exists. I am able to access `/www.domain.com/details?aid=66&lot=35` with no issue, I am only trying to clean up the URL with this Rewrite. I've also tried to point this Rewrite to `index.php?p=488&aid=$1&lot=$2` (_488 is the page's ID in WP_) but this takes me to the `details` page and loses the variables I need it to pass.

Comment: I'm not a WP-fundi, but I'm sure that there's a place where you add your rules to WP itself, considering `details` is a WP page (it is being passed through `index.php`, after all).

Comment: Thanks Mike Rockett. I also went that route. So, what happens when you use the WP built-in function to `add_rewrite_rule` and you "refresh permalinks" it literally adds the exact same line I've got above for my rule except in the section of the `.htaccess` file that is reserved for WordPress rules. Sadly, it still doesn't work.